# Sdl_ttf Text Wrapping

Tags: c++, newline, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

When a string of text goes past say, `300` in length, I want it to drop to a new line and continue. I read that this is how you do it but it's not working - it is just stretching out the text.

How to achieve this?

```
const char* message = "example text to test that it drops to a new line."; 
std::string fontFile = "Font/font.ttf";
int fontSize = 16;

TTF_Font *font = nullptr;
    font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);

SDL_Color textColor = { 0, 300, 200 };
SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(font, message, textColor, 300);
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_p_Renderer, surf);

int w,h;
TTF_SizeText(font,message,&w,&h);

srcRect.x = 0;
srcRect.y = 0;
destRect.x = 0;
destRect.y = 0;

srcRect.w =w;
srcRect.h = h;

destRect.w =w;
destRect.h = h;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A think the error is on `TTF_SizeText(...)` calling. It does not know about the boundary you set and probably ignores endlines too. Try to remove that line an put these instead:

```
int w, h;
w = surf->w;
h = surf->h;
```

I hope it helps.